# Can I run a function only once per process in linqpad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have a Ninject IoC container which has many bindings. I'm binding in my linqpad script.

However, this fails when I try to run more than once, because there are then multiple bindings for the same types on the second run, so when I try to get from the IoC container it fails.

Is there an application start or init function I use from Ninject so the binding only happens once?

In an MVC program for example, I would use Application_Start()

Example: In this program each time the program is run the output count is increased. Is there an application start event I can hook into to reset the count?

My actual needs are to prevent double binding of ninject kernels, so please no "solutions" that fix the singleton, I know it's not thread safe etc!

```
void Main()
{
    {
        var x = Singleton.Instance;
        Console.WriteLine(x.count++);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() { }

    public int count;

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
                instance.count = 0;
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: LINQPad has a "Query -> Cancel All Threads and Reset" option that effectively starts you off from scratch by unloading the whole process, but it's not clear if that's your problem, or if you're truly looking to run multiple instances in parallel.

Comment: @mjwills I'm trying to produce a minimal example but it's tough to try to remove the proprietary code from the source.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, that will work as a workaround but I am eager to see if there is a better solution since compilation adds a lot of overhead to each execution.

Comment: I understand that. No worries, we can wait.

Comment: I've added an example where the output differs each time the program is run through linqpad to demonstrate that static members are not cleaned up per run.

Comment: Ironically I can just use this singleton pattern to prevent the double-initialisation but I'm still keen to hear if there is an application start equivalent so I'll leave the question open.

Comment: You *can* check if things have already happened, through `static`s, and then not do them, but you can *not* reset initialization after it's been done (in general), because that would require unloading the AppDomain/ending the process. That's not specific to LINQPad. Resetting afterwards can only be done if the Ninject API (or whatever other global thing you're dealing with) offers some way to reset bindings after the fact (I don't know if Ninject does, incidentally). The "application start", of course, is literally just `Main`.

Comment: Also, even though you said not to fix the singleton, I can't *help* but remark that the whole thing can be reduced to `static Singleton Instance { get; } = new Singleton();` That's it, one line, thread-safe through framework magic, no further locks or checks needed. Friends don't let friends copy bad code, especially when the safe alternative is shorter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That may well be the case, I literally copied the singleton from msdn at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: MSDN samples have a deserved reputation for being bad in general, but this one I can't fault as much, because at least it clearly has "this content is outdated and is no longer being maintained" at the top. And it even follows up with a thread-safe alternative that's correct (although more wordy than necessary in recent versions of C#). The "lazy initialization" advantage it claims for the first sample is handled by `Lazy<T>` these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realise this happened with statics in LinqPad. Good find.

Have you tried wrap the call to `Application_Start()` with a flag in your `Singleton` class in a similar way to your use of `if(instance == null)`.

Something like...

```
private static bool _initialised;
public static void Initialise()
{
    if(_initialised)
      return;
    _initialise = true;
    something.Application_Start();
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I've ended up going with for now, and it does work.  I won't mark as accepted answer just yet to give others a chance to answer in case someone does find something in the 'this' or linqpad Util class, but I'll come back and accept later if nothing does turn up. p.s. should that first line be private static bool _initialised?

Comment: yeah, private static bool. side note, LinqPad is a vital part of my developer toolbox, so this was a good question